# Importing EGI eeg binary format data into R?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, eeg, analysis

Are there R packages/functions for importing EGI eeg data format into R?

Comment: After a quick google search I found two EEG packages: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eegAnalysis/eegAnalysis.pdf and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eegkit/eegkit.pdf. I do not know if they are compatible with EGI. If matlab would also be a possibility you could look into fieldtrip. That package can do about almost everything.

Answer (score 3):

While the available R packages for EEG do not seem to support the EGI eeg data format (see Robin Kramer's comment), you might want to try [MNE-Python](https://www.martinos.org/mne/stable/index.html) as a free and open alternative to any EEG toolbox implemented in Matlab.

MNE-Python does support the [EGI eeg data format](https://martinos.org/mne/dev/manual/io.html#importing-eeg-data) among many others. Furthermore, there are several comprehensive [examples](https://www.martinos.org/mne/stable/auto_examples/index.html) to get you started.